# Как отличить перечисление от пояснения?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксический-разбор, перечисление, пояснительная

Как отличить перечисление от пояснительной конструкции? В обоих случаях 
иногда можно добавить "а именно". Возьмем пример: **У меня есть три карандаша: синий, красный, зеленый.** А так можно: **У меня есть три карандаша — синий, красный, зеленый**? Здесь перечисление или пояснение? Кажется, двоеточие уместней. А если карандашей два, то двоеточие как-то не хочется ставить, а как это объяснить — не знаю.

> В роли обобщающих слов при однородных членах предложения выступают:
>   1) **родовое понятие** (общее), по отношению к которому однородные члены предложения являются видовыми понятиями (частными): На следующих станциях жадно хватали все газеты: центральные, местные, краевые (Кетл.);
>   2) **название целого**, по отношению к которому однородные члены обозначают части: Но я как будто вижу перед собой эту картину: тихие берега, расширяющуюся лунную дорогу прямо от меня к баржам понтонного моста и на мосту длинные тени бегущих людей (Кав.). [(§ 15. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=76))

Как доказать, что "три карандаша" — обобщающие слова? Можно ли считать "три карандаша" названим целого?

Если "У меня есть карандаши: синий, красный, зеленый", то карандаши — родовое понятие, а "три карандаша"?

Answer (score 1):

1) **Вряд ли следует сравнивать пояснение и перечисление** и тем более различать их, так как это совершенно разные термины. Понятие перечисления связано с однородными рядами, а пояснение — это раскрытие содержания слова с неопределенным значением или замена слова подходящим синонимом для лучшего понимания его смысла. **Это можно сделать разными способами, в то числе и с помощью однородного ряда.**

Но вот в теме "Знаки препинания при однородных членах предложения с обобщающими словами" эти термины могут присутствовать, но там у них не главная роль.

2) **В принципе любой однородный ряд может иметь обобщающее слово**, это связано с самим понятием однородности: между собой члены ряда (предметы, например)  независимы, но им можно подобрать общее название.

У Розенталя дается информация о том, какие слова могут быть обобщающими, у Лопатина этого нет, и это правильно. **Просто нельзя определить все возможные варианты обобщающих слов, и нет смысла это делать**. Однородный ряд поясняет, конкретизирует, раскрывает содержание обобщающего слова, если это входит в авторскую (коммуникативную) задачу.

**3) Например:**

У тебя есть какие-нибудь цветные карандаши? — У меня  **три карандаша** —  синий, красный, зеленый.

Какие  цветные карандаши у тебя есть? — У меня  **три карандаша**: синий, красный, зеленый.

Или: У меня **два карандаша**, синий и красный. Если ряд включает два предмета, то их можно объединить союзом И и обособить запятой. Такое оформление характерно для пояснительных членов, а не однородного ряда.

**4) И вывод.**

**Обобщающее слово может иметь разную природу**: родовое понятие, или целое по отношению к частям, или слово с неопределенным значением, или числовой оборот. Всё это непринципиально, так как его единственная функция — **обобщить** предметы, признаки, действия, составляющие  однородный ряд. А ряд в свою очередь  должен **пояснять, конкретизировать, перечислять** то, что названо обобщающим словом.